# How to implement "NSUserDefaults" functionality equivalent in Corona?

Tags: iphone, lua, nsuserdefaults, coronasdk

All I want is to save my user(player) highscores, and this information to persist between application(game) launches in Corona SDK (Lua). I do want it to work on iOS and Android nicely. My highscores data is actually two lua tables containing numbers.

What's the correct and easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may save the scores into a table, and then serialize it into json format text file.

```
local json=require("json")
local savefile="scores.json"

scores= 
    {
        {
            level=1,
            status=0,
            highscore=0,
        },
        {
            level=2,
            status=0,
            highscore=0,
        },
    }

function getScore(filename, base)
    -- set default base dir if none specified
    if not base then 
        base = system.DocumentsDirectory 
    end

    -- create a file path for corona i/o
    local path = system.pathForFile(filename, base)

    -- will hold contents of file
    local contents

    -- io.open opens a file at path. returns nil if no file found
    local file = io.open(path, "r")
        local scores
    if file then
        -- read all contents of file into a string
        contents = file:read( "*a" )
            if content ~= nil then
            scores=json.decode(content)
            end
        io.close(file) -- close the file after using it
    end

    return scores
end

function saveScore(filename, base)
    -- set default base dir if none specified
    if not base then 
        base = system.DocumentsDirectory 
    end

    -- create a file path for corona i/o
    local path = system.pathForFile(filename, base)

    -- io.open opens a file at path. returns nil if no file found
    local file = io.open(path, "wb")
    if file then
        -- write all contents of file into a string
        file:write(json.encode(scores))
        io.close(file) -- close the file after using it
    end
end
```

The global `scores` variable can be manipulated like a normal table, and when you want to load or save the `scores` table you can call the functions above.

Comment: Note that if you're going to use Game Center or another online leaderboard service, you need to encrypt this database or users with jailbroken phones can just edit the table to show whatever score they want and then reopen the app, artificially raising their online score.

Comment: cctan: Great, thanks alot!! Exactly what I was looking for and beyond.
Jack: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know that.Will do when I implement game center.

Comment: @JackLawrence +1 for mentioning encryption